# Convergent sequence of monotone sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_k: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+, k \ge 1\}$ for which $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)$$ is absolutely convergent for all $0 < x < \infty$.  Now suppose I have a monotonically decreasing sequence $x_1 > x_2 > ...$

Does there exist $0 < x < \infty$ such that $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)?$$

Comment: Thanks.
Why is that?  If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_m)$ is convergent for all $x_m$'s, wouldn't this imply that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_k)$ is convergent?  Am I missing a condition?

Comment: Set $f_k(x)=\frac1{2^kx}$ That means you have absolute convergence for each $x$, but $f_k(\frac1{2^k})=1$.

Comment: Right.  Thanks!  What if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_k)$ is convergent?

Comment: Even then not necessarily. Define $x_k=\frac1{2^k},f_k(x_k)=x_k$ and make $f_k(x)$ increasing for $x < x_k$ (say linear) and decreasing for $x > x_k$ (say exponential with negative exponent). Then $0 < f_k(x) \le \frac1{2^k}$, so absolute convergence for each $x$, but your LHS of the sum is a maximum that can never be reached by the RHS for any $x$.

Comment: Just saw your comment @Ingix , you should have made this an answer. Post it and I will remove mine.

Comment: Just keep your answer, no problem.

Comment: You both answered at the same time.  Can I keep both?  (New user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_k(x)$ an hat function with maximum being $\frac 1 {k^2}$ at $\frac 1 k$ with support $[0,\frac 2 k]$.

let $x_k = \frac 1 k$.

Then :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_k) < \infty$$

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, since we have choosen $x_k$ such that $f(x_k)$ is maximum, then :

$$f_k(x) \le f_k(x_k).$$

But, furthermore, we can find some $N$ such that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{N} f_k(x).$$

Indeed, take $N$ the minimum $k$ such that $\frac 2 k <x$.

Note that $\forall k, f_k(x_k) >0$, then we can conclude that :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{N} f_k(x) < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x_k).$$

Since $x$ was arbitrary, it holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
Hence, no $x$ can be found such that your equation holds.

Comment: I'd rather opt for a hat function with maximum $1\over k$. Then by thoughtful selection of $x_k$ we would be able to make $\sum f_k(x_k)$ either diverge, or converge to literally _any_ number we want in $\mathbb R_+$. Also, things would be simpler with support $\left[{1\over2^k},{1\over2^{k-1}}\right]$, because then every $\sum f_k(x)$ will have _only one_ non-zero term.

Comment: Just apply those suggestions to your answer then. @IvanNeretin

Comment: What if $f_k(x)$ is a decreasing monotone sequence, i.e., $f_1(x) > f_2(x) > ...$?

Comment: Then consider the same sequence $x_k = \frac 1 k$ with $f_k(x) = \frac 1 {k^2}$ on $[0,\frac 1 k]$ then going linearly down to $\frac 1 {k^3}$ at $x= \frac 2 {k}$ and $\frac 1 {k^3}$ otherwise. @SEJ

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the conjecture does not always hold, because the LHS does not necessarily converge.

Say, $f_k(x)=e^{-kx}$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ is a geometric progression and surely does converge for any fixed $x>0$, just as you wanted. Now select $x_k={1\over k}$. Then $f_k(x_k)={1\over e}$, so their sum is...

Comment: But, what if LHS converges ?